# Bloodpyre Poison Str bonus duration

Tags: pathfinder-1e, conditions, poison, duration

This [bloodpyre](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/bloodpyre/) poison states that it gives str bonus along with the damage it causes. However there is no duration given. Does the str bonus last while you have ability score damage? Is it permanent? Or is there some other duration that I just have not seen or found?

Here are a few other poisons that I looked at in reference before asking here.

[Nerveblast](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/nerveblast/) - Has listed duration for its secondary effect. 
[Blue Star](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/blue-star/) - Persists 1 week after it runs out.
[Sword Witch Hunters](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/sword-witch-hunters/) - uses the wording "As long as the poison persists"
[Crone's Curse](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/crones-curse/) - uses the wording "During this time"
[Rage Spittle](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/ragespittle/) - Lists no explicit duration from its secondary effect

With these examples, I can see an argument for the bonus only lasting the frequency, and I can see it lasting longer. I have nothing in the [d20 poison section](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/) that states their effects end when the poison runs its course, and nothing in [this paizo FAQ section about poison](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo5lc12?I-Drank-What-An-FAQ-on-Poison) that states similar. Please note I am looking for an official ruling. If one doesn't exist that is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

## It lasts as long as the poison

Poisons [last](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/) until they run out of duration (that would normally be 6 rounds, unless you are exposed to more doses, for Bloodpyre) or are cured.  Curing a poison removes its ongoing effects, which would include, for bloodpyre, the str bonus.  The ability score damage would need to be removed separately-- it's not an ongoing effect, but you could also remove or prevent that damage without removing or preventing the str bonus.  For example, a character immune to ability score damage and fire, but *not* immune to poison, would receive the str bonus with none of the drawbacks and could voluntarily fail the saving throw to keep those benefits until the duration of the poison expired.

Comment: Poison's duration is listed under frequency. The statement they have no duration is false. Your answer would mean that the strength bonus would last 6 rounds only (and not even at full bonus). While ability damage would last up to 6 days with rest. Now if that is what you are implying that is fine, but if you could please cite references for me.

Comment: Although I believe this would be correct with the inclusion of the 6 round limit. (you have the bonus for 6 rounds, but any damage accrued remains)

Comment: [Related forum topic](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2tk3q?Poison-Bloodpyre)

Comment: I saw that forum post. It didnt really offer a concrete answer. 

So you are saying that if you fail every save, you will have 1str for 6 rounds, 2 for 5, 3 for 4, 4 for 2 rounds, 5 for 1, and 6 for none because the poison is over when you hit round 6? -- all for the steep steep cost of 6 ability damage to each mental stat, and 12d6 fire damage?

Comment: @Erudaki The poison is only over when you hit round six if you've not been exposed to more of it.  The fire damage and mental ability damage can be mitigated.  But, yes, using a single dose and failing every save would work that way.

Comment: I do not see where it says all effects of the poison end when the poison runs its course. It only states that it does not have repeated effects. Several poisons have lasting effects and cause effects that linger after the poison's frequency runs out. Further more "so some drow houses enhance their warriors with bloodpyre despite the pain and damage it causes." this line seems to be counter to what you are saying. If possible can you please quote or reference where you are getting the idea that the bonus stops when the effect ends?

Comment: I would think +6 for one round (continues to "last" on the final turn that you Save/don't save on) if its not re-applied (or else prepared with something to increase its duration). Ofc that's just what I would *rule* as I've found no better rule distinction for it. Don't forget its also 1000g per dose; not a wall for any reasonably high creature, but definitely substantial for a consumable

Comment: If were talking about rulings due to lack of stated duration, I argue the other way. For the bonus to last as long as the damage. Otherwise 1000g + 6 days of ability score damage and ~42 fire damage for worse than a scroll of bull strength? I dont think it would make a great poison.... Sure it would be okay on spellcasters but there's better for cheaper.  Def not worth using on martial foe. -- However, I came here hoping for a more official ruling that I may have missed. Doesn't seem like there is one. I was really hoping he could point to where he read that poison effects last their duration.